# Excel date format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with dates in the following format: 20120529

I could change it manually to 29-05-2012, but it will take a long time since I have more than five thousand rows, is there any way to change the date format automatically for every row?

Comment: Is it actually a string, or a number, or is it a strangely formatted date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're dealing with a string/number. If it's a date, simply format the date to `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Otherwise, you could break it down using the string manipulation functions mid, left and right:

```
=(right(A1,2)&"/"&mid(A1,5,2)&"/"&left(A1,4))*1
```

Then format as `dd-mm-yyyy` through 'Format Cells'. I believe there might be some issues if the regional settings are in US instead of UK. If it's the former and you do get issues with the first formula, I would use:

```
=(mid(A1,5,2)&"/"&right(A1,2)&"/"&left(A1,4))*1
```

Then format as `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was trying to do something like that but didn't know what functions to use.

Answer (score 3):

of course you can!

Use the date function

> DATE(year,month,day)

Assuming your date in YYYYMMDD is in A1, put this in B1:

```
 =DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2))
```

Comment: This is cleaner than Jerry's answer. I wrote the same answer without seeing yours - except I used `MID(A1, 7, 2)` for the days.

Comment: Formatting the cell properly if you really want to display hyphens is indeed the way to go. It's always better to keep dates, timestamps, etc. in the appropriate format rather than a string!